# Laravel auth cannot logout and User session always filled

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.7

I use default auth from Laravel 5.7, and make some changes to the login page display. I have logged in several times and can run normally, after I stayed a day, and I opened my app again, I found a problem, where the user I last used was still logged in (no logout / user session remained), even though already restarted. when I try to logout (using the logout function) it can get an error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

I'm not sure, is this a bug from the "Remember me" feature or not.
I have been looking for a solution, but I didn't find it, maybe because of my incorrect query.

- For LoginController, midleware auth etc. it's still in a standard state, I have never changed it

Logout function
[image: error logout function]

My login form
[image: login form]

this is my route
[image: my route]

route list 1
[image: route list]

[image: route list]

route list 2

Comment: The thrown exception means there is something wrong with your routes. Please make sure it is defined as a GET route and not as a POST (or something else)! If you don't know what do do please provide us your routes.

Comment: no, didn't changed my auth route, i just add some route method  for my UserController

Comment: Hmm, strange! Could you provide me the output of php artisan route:list?

Comment: i has been update my question

Comment: i has been solved, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5.4+ uses `post` method for logout so instead of simple url (`get`) request you should post a form to logout.

Try Something Like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> Logout</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Comment: it's work, i don't know how it give different result with my logout method

Comment: this is my code `<li><a href="{{route('logout')}}"><i class="ti-power-off m-r-10 text-danger"></i> Logout</a></li>`

Comment: and how it take effect with my user session ? can you explain it please ?

Comment: Hope you understood. You were doing simple get method.